# Postman REST API Call To Parse Server Not Working In Javascript Website

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, parse-platform, postman

I have a Parse API Server ([www.parse.com](http://www.parse.com))hosted on Azure which I can make a REST API Call to without issue using Postman.  When I translate this into my web app (using the Postman jQuery AJAX code snippet generator), I receive a 400 (bad request) response in the browser.

Initially, I am successfully calling the API through postman as follows:

- **FUNCTION:** Post
- **URL:** https://myparsewebapp.azurewebsites.net/parse/classes/_User
- **HEADERS:** X-Parse-Application-Id = (My Application ID Set In The Azure CP)
- **BODY:** {"username":"firstuser","password":"shushitsasecret","email":"myemail@gmail.com"}

With the above, I can successfully create a new user in Parse Server. Great!

Next, I copy the code using the Postman Generator & receive the following output:

```
  var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://myparsewebapp.azurewebsites.net/parse/classes/_User",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "x-parse-application-id": "(My Application ID Set In The Azure CP)",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "2a3c4ffc-b636-3ac4-bd7c-e559f7bced1b"
  },
  "data": "{\n    \"username\":\"firstuser\",\n    \"password\":\"shushitsasecret\",\n    \"email\":\"myemail@gmail.com\"\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**Note that in my source code I removed the cache-control & postman-token headers**.

I take this & place it into my Angular 1 app, with the following form:

```
<div id="register_form" style="display: none">
    <button type="button" class="uk-position-top-right uk-close uk-margin-right uk-margin-top back_to_login" ng-click="backToLogin($event)"></button>
    <h2>Create an account</h2>
    <form id="register">
        <div class="uk-form-row">
            <label for="register-username">Username</label>
            <input id="register-username" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="uk-form-row">
            <label for="register-password">Password</label>
            <input id="register-password" type="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="uk-form-row">
            <label for="register-email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="text" id="register-email" />
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin-medium-top">
            <input id="register-submit" type="submit" value="Sign Up!" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I then alter data to read as follows:

```
"data": "{\"username\":\""+name+"\",\"password\":\""+password+"\",\"email\":\""+email+"\"}",
```

My full Javascript snippet looks like this:

```
$("#register").submit(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var name = $("#register-username").val();
                    var password = $("#register-password").val();
                    var email = $("#register-email").val();

                    var settings = {
                        "async": true,
                        "crossDomain": true,
                        "url": "https://myparsewebapp.azurewebsites.net/parse/classes/_User",
                        "method": "POST",
                        "headers": {
                            "x-parse-application-id": "(My Application ID Set In The Azure CP)"
                        },
                        "data": "{\"username\":\""+name+"\",\"password\":\""+password+"\",\"email\":\""+email+"\"}",
                    }
                    console.log(settings);
                    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                });
```

The console.log output for the settings is as follows:

```
Object
async
:
true
crossDomain
:
true
data
:
"{"username":"admin","password":"secret","email":"myemail@gmail.com"}"
headers
:
Object
x-parse-application-id
:
"(My Application ID Set In The Azure CP)"
__proto__
:
Object
method
:
"POST"
url
:
"https://myparsewebapp.azurewebsites.net/parse/classes/_User"
__proto__
:
Object
```

Around 1 minute later, I then get the following response output:

```
POST https://myparsewebapp.azurewebsites.net/parse/classes/_User 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: are you sending this as pure text? probably your server don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send json then you need to set `contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8'` since the default for `$.ajax` is to send a form encoded request.

Beyond that you will need to make sure that CORS is enabled in your api if request is cross domain. REST clients like Postman are not subject to CORS restrictions

Comment: As in:  var settings = {
                        contentType: 'json',
                        "async": true,
                        "crossDomain": true,
                        "url": "https://myparsewebapp.azurewebsites.net/parse/classes/_User",
                        "method": "POST",
                        "headers": {
                            "x-parse-application-id": "myidremoved"
                        },
                        "data": "{\"username\":\""+name+"\",\"password\":\""+password+"\",\"email\":\""+email+"\"}",
                    }

Comment: Also, when I don't remove "cache-control": "no-cache" from the headers, I get a CORS error.

Comment: So you need cors enabled

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?  I'm not sure how you do (or if you can) enable CORS on Parse.

Comment: Fixed it!  You were close.  I had to instead add **dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",** & it worked.  Alter your post & I'll tick it off!

Comment: Didn't need to do anything with CORS in the end.

Comment: Oh that was my bad...I recommended wrong value and should have known better